# How to stop video in ie8 when hiding a div?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, dreamweaver, flvplayer

I have written some JavaScript that will display a video when someone clicks on a picture and then they can click on the "x" to close the video but the video continues to play in ie8 when hidden but stops with FireFox and Chrome. If anyone can tell me how to fix this by having the video stop when the "xbutton" image is clicked I'd greatly appreciate it I have been fighting with this for hours. This is what I have so for JavaScript:

```
    function toggle(div_id) {
       var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
       if ( el.style.display == 'none' ) {  el.style.display = 'block';}
       else {el.style.display = 'none';}    }

    function blanket_size(popUpDivVar) {
      var blanket = document.getElementById('blanket');
      blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight;           
      blanket.style.height = blanket_height + 'px'; 
          }

    function popup(windowname) {
       blanket_size(windowname);    
       toggle('blanket');
       toggle(windowname);  
           }
```

and this is the html I am using. I am just using dreamweaver to add a .flv video file from my computer.

```
    <div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;">
    <a href="#popUpDiv" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')"><img 
    src="../New images/newxbtn-red.png" class ="xbutton" alt = "Close"/></a>
    <p> Video Header</p>
    <!--Dreamweaver video code starts here -->
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="622"
    height="350" id="FLVPlayer">
    <param name="movie" value="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
    <param name="salign" value="lt" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="FlashVars" 
    value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=Halo_Skin_3&amp;streamName=video/bf-
    eng&amp;autoPlay=true&amp;autoRewind=false" />
    <param name="swfversion" value="8,0,0,0" />
    <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download 
    the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the 
    prompt. -->
    <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
     <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
     <!--[if !IE]>-->
     <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf"  
     width="622" height="350">
     <!--<![endif]-->
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
    <param name="salign" value="lt" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="FlashVars"  
    value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=Halo_Skin_3&amp;streamName=video/bf-  
    eng&amp;autoPlay=true&amp;autoRewind=false" />
    <param name="swfversion" value="8,0,0,0" />
    <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
    <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash 
    Player 
    6.0 and older. -->'
    <div>
   <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img 
   src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif"  
   alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
   </div>
   <!--[if !IE]>-->   
   </object>
   <!--<![endif]-->
   </object>
    <!-- Video Ends -->
     </div>
     <div class ="image">   
     <a href="#popUpDiv" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">
     <img src="img/farmers/Donahue_Beef.jpg" width="190" height="110" alt="Beef" />
     <img src="../New images/playbtn.png" width="200" height="116" alt="Play" class = 
     "play"/></a>
     </div>
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

There may be a very easy way using jQuery. In my case I generated a flash embed div with object in it. With jQuery you can easily define a close button with the `empty()` function on click. This clears the content of the div and the video is no longer in the DOM.

```
$("#video a.close").click(function(){
 $("#flashlayer").empty();
}
```

Comment: If you want back the video again, you will have get it from server again using this approach, or you will have to ask the user to refresh the page. Both does not that sounding usability.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll have to listen for the `click` event on your `xbutton` element (which I recommend adding an ID to):

```
function listen(event, elem, func) {
  if (elem.addEventListener) {
    elem.addEventListener(event, func, false);
  } else if (elem.attachEvent) {
    elem.attachEvent(event, func);
  }
}

listen('load', window, function() {
  var xbutton = document.getElementById('xbutton');
  var player = document.getElementById('FLVPlayer');
  listen('click', xbutton, function(e) {
    player.Stop();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

You can use the JavaScript method `Stop()` to stop your Flash video.

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for answering, I have put in the code that dreamweaver generates when I chose the add a video option. The video has a stop button but I need the video to stop playing once the pop div is closed when clicking "x" because you can still hear the audio once the div is hidden.

Comment: It helps to know that the video is Flash. Let me do some research.